# Model to Recognize if a Business Is a Small Agency

Tags: classification

I'm trying to take a list of companies and see if they're a small business agency.

There are two parts of that process.  We want to identify if they are:

1. An Agency (marketing, graphic design, branding, etc)
2. Small (2-20 people)

I can recognize them when I see them, but it is quite a time consuming task.  Third party data providers often incorrectly classify.

There are on the order of 100,000 of these businesses in the US.

My questions are:

1. What category does a problem like this fall into?
2. What kind of solution would be the best fit?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does the data look like? Do you only have a list of company names? What do you mean by *I can recognize them when I see them, but it is quite a time consuming task*? Looking at their websites?

Comment: Great questions!  I have a list that has the company name, website and LinkedIn page.  I check their LinkedIn page and website to figure out if they're actually a B2B service agency.

Comment: I would propose to (web) scrape the data from the respective sites and gather different key words in order to classify/cluster the sites. It's a very general answer but the task you are describing is non-trivial since it comprises different steps of data processing and potentially highly heterogeneous data in terms of actual texts/contents and formats/layouts.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver!  Web scraping could work and is a quick solution.  Appreciate the simplicity.